# Get an array of the number of post per year of a custom post type (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called "papers", and, to feed a chart, I need an array of the number of posts per year that have posts.

I've tried with `wp_count_posts()` but it just give me the total number of post types, and `get_archives()` is just to static, and I need to use specific information like the number of post per year.

Does anyone know how to do this? Hope you can help me.

Comment: Use wp_count_posts() function for this. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_posts/ . Also what you mean by "array of number of posts" ?

Comment: Hi, `wp_count_posts()` function does give me the amount of post of my custom post type, but I need the amount of post I have per year for that CPT

Comment: If you want cost count and also post data is array formate then you should try this: $posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'      => 'your custom post type',
    'post_status'    => 'all',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who has been wondering the same thing, I got it from other forum:

> I have created a basic example on how you could achieve this result.

```
// get all posts from our CPT no matter the status
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'      => 'papers', // based on the post type from your qeustion
    'post_status'    => 'all',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
]);

// will contain all posts count by year
// every year will contain posts count by status (added as extra =])
$posts_per_year = [];

// start looping all our posts
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // get the post created year
    $post_created_year = get_the_date('Y', $post);

    // check if year exists in our $posts_per_year
    // if it doesn't, add it
    if (!isset($posts_per_year[$post_created_year])) {
        // add the year, add the posts stauts with the initial amount 1 (count)
        $posts_per_year[$post_created_year] = [
            $post->post_status => 1
        ];
    // year already exists, "append" to that year the count
    } else {
        // check if stauts already exists in our year
        // if it exist, add + 1 to the count
        if (isset($posts_per_year[$post_created_year][$post->post_status])) {
            $posts_per_year[$post_created_year][$post->post_status] += 1;
        // it doesnt exist, add the post type to the year with the inital amount 1 (count)
        } else {
            $posts_per_year[$post_created_year][$post->post_status] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Get the complete answer here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/395928/get-an-array-of-the-number-of-post-per-year-of-a-custom-post-type-wordpress/396047#396047

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To get posts published from last year

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'] - 1,
        ),
    ),
);
$result = new WP_Query($args);
$count = $result->found_posts;
echo $count;
```

Other different ways

```
$args = array(
    'type'              => 'yearly',
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'show_post_count'   => true
);
wp_get_archives($args);
```

This will output the following
2015 (5)
2014 (3)
2011 (10)

Comment: Hi, thanks for yout answer but that's not what I'm looking for. I need an array that counts how many post I have for each year I have publish in my custom post type.